# trouble with ggmap rendering a map

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I've been struggling to get a map to render with ggmap. I know this is has been asked before, but after trying to go trouble shoot the problem, and research it here, I still can't get my map to render.

Specifically, the map renders with latitude and longitude coordinates, but the map its self is blank. Here is the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggmap)
library(lubridate)

register_google(key = <My API Key>)
map1 <- get_googlemap(center = c(40.215, -75.370), maptype = "roadmap",
                      source = "google")
```

When I run `ggmap(map1)` I get the following map:
[blank map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKhVQ.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about those coordinates? You might have swapped your longitude & latitude. If you zoom way out, like to zoom = 3, you'll see that this is Antarctica! Swapping the coords gets you somewhere in the suburbs of Philly, which is more likely where you're trying to map

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: Inorder to avoid confusion, try something like this `center = c(lon = -95.3632715, lat = 29.7632836)`